# Android - Why do clearing the external browser cache also clears WebView's cache?

Tags: android, caching, browser, webview, external

I am working on a native Android app that uses a `WebView` to display a login page. We have found a few edge case bugs that might happen depending on what is in the WebView cache/cookies.

To my surprise though, when we open the ***external*** browser of the phone and clear its cache, we found the WebView cache **of the app** is also cleared.

I thought the WebView implementation was completely separated from the external browser, but it looks like they share the cache somehow?

I don't understand how this works. Does anybody know why the WebView appears to share caching with the native browser (or can point me to any external resource about this)?

Answer (score 1):

The default directory is being deleted because it is used.

[Helpful](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#setDataDirectorySuffix(java.lang.String))